# Spring boot FF4j ff4j-spring-boot-starter excluding swagger doc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ff4j

I need in my spring boot application `FF4j`. I try

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.ff4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>ff4j-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

and in this case my application is broken because of swagger.

can I exclude `org.ff4j.spring.boot.web.api.config.SwaggerConfig` from my configuration?

I tried to manage it but cant reach final solution because of new different issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you configure `swagger` in your application in usual case it will be failed because of different reasons. Possible next ones:

- spring needs resolve which swagger bean should be used;
- cg-lib conflict in case you used bean name `api`;
- swagger conflict because two different `Docket` beans in same spring context;

  1. Firstly I tried to exclude `ff4j-spring` auto configuration configuring steps in similar way but excluding `swagger` for example. Application can't start `ff4j` without their swagger. That's confused a lot.
  2. Looking different solutions I tried follow some recommendations [like](https://github.com/ff4j/ff4j-spring-boot-starter-parent/issues/27#issuecomment-466533139) but I'm getting different issue with missed class for my application. Missed class is in `thymeleaf5`. I can't use `thymeleaf5` because of it uses same name interface but different arguments. Additional workarounds make my application failed because of hibernate.

### Swagger solution is:

in your configuration inject `swagger` `Docket` from `ff4j`:

```
@Autowired
Docket api;
```

and rewrite `api` with your configuration in `@PostConstruct` block. This solution is not elegant, but provides fix for swagger configs.

```
@PostConstruct
public void reconfigureSwagger() {
  api....
}
```

### P.S.

After swagger issue I've got more unresolved elements (but that's will be a different questions).

### P.S.2.

`FF4j` library provides great UI and ideas and this is general reason why I do not avoid of its headache.